# Mechanize::ResponseReadError - Content-Length does not match response body length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I have encountered this error while requesting a page with Mechanize:

> Mechanize::ResponseReadError
> Content-Length (17317) does not match
>   response body length (17070) (Mechanize::ResponseReadError)

Any thoughts on why this occurs and how I could get about fixing it are much appreciated!

Comment: Can you intercept the response and check to see whether the response body is indeed shorter than the Content-Length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens that sites return a wrong content length-value. Catch the error and force page parsing.

```
agent = Mechanize.new
begin
  page = agent.get 'http://bad.com'
rescue Mechanize::ResponseReadError => e
  page = e.force_parse
end
```

You can also set `agent.ignore_bad_chunking` to true — but then beware of possible silent content loss.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs because `Content-Length` header is  not equal to the size of `response-body` length.

Check the below specs taken by [mechanize gem](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/blob/153c3cb78c6528a92add007b32a407b03ce90b62/test/test_mechanize_http_agent.rb#L1324-L1334).  it will raise same error.

```
  def test_response_read_content_length_mismatch
    def @res.content_length() 5 end
    def @res.read_body() yield 'part' end

    e = assert_raises Mechanize::ResponseReadError do
      @agent.response_read @res, @req, @uri
    end

    assert_equal 'Content-Length (5) does not match response body length (4)' \
      ' (Mechanize::ResponseReadError)', e.message
  end
```